# Почему C++ может преобразовать int* в const int*, но с ** так же не может?

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

Есть такой код (ничего не делает, приведён просто для примера):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int f(const int *)
{
    return 0;
}

int main() 
{
    int * x = new int;
    f(x);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Здесь (в коде выше) всё работает.

**Но** в таком коде:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int f(const int **) // Добавил ещё одну *
{
    return 0;
}

int main() 
{
    int * x = new int;
    f(&x); // Теперь передаю адрес указателя

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio выдаёт ошибку:

> `"int f(const int **)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "int**"
>   в "const int **"`

Не пойму, в чём **принципиальная** разница между `int*` и `int**`. Почему одно преобразовывается без проблем, а другое нет?

Comment: Это заезженный FAQ, на который уже 500 раз отвечали. К сожалению, трудно сформировать запрос для поиска ответа на такой вопрос.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Это сделано для избегания потенциального неявного присвоения исходному указателю указателя на неизменяемый объект минуя `const_cast`:

```
int const val{};
int * p_val;
p_val = &val; // не прокатывает

int const * * pp_val{&p_val}; // предположим что эта строка работает
*pp_val = &val; // исходный указатель теперь тоже указывает на неизменяемый объект val
*p_val = 42;
```

Чтобы заработал исходный пример достаточно будет добавить еще один `const` квалификатор.

```
int f(int const * const *)
```

Преобразование `int * *` в `int const * const *` будет разрешено так как оно не создает описанную выше проблему:

```
int const * const * pp_val{&p_val}; // работает
*pp_val = &val; // не прокатывает
```

Comment: Разве не логичнее было бы запретить `*pp_val = &val;` это из первого примера? Мы ведь получаем значение, хранящееся по адресу `pp_val` и это значение типа `int *` и мы пытаемся присвоить ему значение типа `int const *`. Это выглядит более неправильно, чем присвоение `int const**` типа `int **`. (Я понимаю, что, наверное, не логичнее, раз так не сделали. Объясните, почему)

Comment: "Навесить" квалификатор `const` безопаснее, чем снять его, разве нет?

Comment: @V-Mor `значение, хранящееся по адресу pp_val и это значение типа int *` -  нет, начение, хранящееся по адресу `pp_val` - это значение типа `int const *`

Comment: То есть `int const **` – это указатель на константный указатель, а не константный указатель на указатель? (Надеюсь Вы поняли, простите за ужасную тавтологию).

Comment: Вы запустили во мне процесс коренного переосмысления указателей C++ :) Спасибо за Ваш ответ, он был действительно полезен.

Comment: @V-Mor `int const **` - это изменяемый указатель на изменяемый указатель на неизменяемый `int`.